# Given a number n, how many balanced binary trees (not binary search trees) are there?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

The definition of `balanced` in this question is

> The number of nodes in its left subtree and the number of nodes in its
>   right subtree are almost equal, which means their difference is not
>   greater than one

if given a `n` as the number of nodes in total, how many are there such trees?

---

Also what if we replace `the number of nodes` with `height`? Given a `height`, how many height balanced trees are there?

Comment: Homework? Try writing down a recurrent formula for the number of trees with 2*N and 2*N+1 nodes (also for the number of trees with height h+1). You may want to consider the number of trees with N=2^k-1 nodes.

Comment: @n.m. nah, it is not home work, just self improvement. Yes, I tried that, but it is a combination of two occations. I am wondering whether there is a unique equation where I give n and get ans directly

Comment: @Jackson - It seems all your conditions are similar to that of AVL trees. Are you speaking about AVL trees?

Comment: @arunb2w AVL trees are the second definition, with height difference of at most 1, not the initial definition of number of nodes difference at most 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the difference will be made only by the last level, hence you can just find how many nodes should be left for that one, and just consider all possible combinations. Having `n` nodes you know that the height should be `floor(log(n))` hence the same tree at depth `k = floor(log(n)) - 1` is fully balanced, hence you know that is needs (`m = sum(i=0..k)2^i`) nodes, hence `n-m` nodes are left for the last level. Some definition of a balanced binary tree force "all the nodes to be left aligned", in this case it is obvious that there can be only one possibility, without this constraint you have combinations of `2^floor(log(n))` chooses `n-m`, because you have to pick which of the `2^floor(log(n))` possible slots you will assign with nodes, forcing a total of `n-m` nodes to be assigned.

For the height story you consider a sum of combinations of `2^floor(log(n))` chooses `i` as `i` goes from 1 to `2^floor(log(n))`. You consider all possibilities of having either 1 node at the last level, then 2 and so on, until you don't make it a fully balanced binary tree, hence having all `2^floor(log(n))` slots assigned.